# The tags for cosmic microwave background need merging

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

It seems like there are two tags referring to the cosmic microwave background, [cmb](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cmb) and [cosmic-microwave-background](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmic-microwave-background).

Should they be merged?

Comment: done! ..........